# How can I change the command used to open an application?

Tags: taskbar, context-menu

Ubuntu 22.04LTS.

In Kubuntu (for instance) I could right-click on a program's icon and select "Properties" and add command line switches. In Ubuntu, that option doesn't exist.

The basic day-to-day stuff is simplified for ease of use, I presume, but I like having more options than fewer.

Any way to get to the application command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons which you see in the Dash or in the Applications Overview come from a set of `.desktop` files.

The format of a `.desktop` file is given in the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/) by [FreeDesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/).

The system-wide `.desktop` files live in `/usr/share/applications/` or, for snappified applications, in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`.

In order to modify one of them, *copy* it to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` and edit the copy. When a file in your `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` is found with the same name as a system-wide file it takes precedence, so that your modified copy will be used in preference to the system-wide file.

(Note that for some silly reason a desktop file needs to have the executable bit set -- `rwxr-xr-x` works fine. Gnome is strange. Make sure that you don't change the mode of the file when copying it.)

For example, if you right-click on the Firefox icon in the Dash, by default it offers two actions: Open a New Window and Open a New Private Window. Let's add a third action, Open Google in a New Window:

1. Copy the system-wide Firefox desktop description file to your per-user applications folder:

   ```
   cd ~/.local/share/applications
   cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop .
   ```

   (Assuming that you have the snappified Firefox which is bundled with the system. If you have replaced it with a natively installed Firefox, you will copy it from `/usr/share/applications/`.)
2. Edit the private copy of the `.desktop` file:

   ```
   gedit firefox_firefox.desktop
   ```
3. The file has the general structure of an `.ini` file, that is, stanzas with names in `[`brackets`]` and zero or more assignments of the form <setting>`=`<value> in each stanza.
4. The first stanza is `[Desktop Entry]`. In this stanza you will find a line saying `Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;`, which gives the names of the stanzas describing the predefined actions. Edit it to say `Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;NewGoogleWindow;`.
5. Then add at the end of the file a stanza named `[Desktop Action NewGoogleWindow]` by copying the `[Desktop Action NewWindow]` stanza.

   - You see a line with `Name=`; this is what gets displayed when you right click the icon in the Dash or in the Applications Overview.
   - The `Name[`xx`]=` lines give translations in various languages; you can safely delete them, except maybe the line giving the translation in your native language, if you want it.
   - The line `Exec=` gives the command line to be executed. Some characters have special meanings; be sure to read the [relevant part](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html#exec-variables) of the specification.

     The best is to change the `Exec=` line you have copied as little as possible; for the example, this is changed to

     ```
     Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox -new-window https://www.google.com
     ```

     (This is a long line. Scroll to the right to see all of it.)

     (Again, this is for the snappified Firefox as shipped with the system. If you have replaced it with a natively installed Firefox, the details may be different.)
6. Save the edited copy, log out and log in again. (Because the `.desktop` files are read only when starting a new user session. *"GNOME is designed to help you have the best possible computing experience."*)